# selenium+argparse - change browser with command line argument

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, argparse

I want to create a selenium script and use argparse to choose the browser from the command line. This is what I have - when I run `test.py chrome`, nothing happens.

test.py:

https://repl.it/repls/ProbableHeavenlySystem

```
from selenium import webdriver
import argparse


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('chrome')
    parser.add_argument('firefox')
    parser.parse_args()
    args = parser.parse_args()


def pick_browser(args):
    if args.chrome == 'chrome':
        return args.webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/pathto/chromedriver.exe')
elif args.firefox == 'firefox':
    return args.webdriver.Firefox(
        executable_path='C:/pathto/geckodriver.exe')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys.argv`:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

in command line type `python script.py chrome` and in script file:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[1]) # prints chrome
```

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm) you can find a good tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, but I will use many arguments (about 20), also I want to create a documentation (-h) for this script, so I have to use argparse

Comment: I've edited my code a little (changed args.chrome is 'chrome' to args.chrome == 'chrome')